# How to select database at the run-time of creating tables using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating database and tables at the run-time. When I execute code it is creating database but not tables. It throws an error :"No database selected";
                                                                         Please guide me.

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $db_name";
if ($this->db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $errors = [];

    $table1 = "CREATE TABLE `login_detail` (
                `id` int(100)  UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                `employee_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                `full_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
                `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                `profile_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1')";

    $table2 = "INSERT INTO `login_detail` 
                        (`id`, `employee_id`, `full_name`, 
                        `password`, `role`, `profile_image`, `status`) 
                VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 
                        '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', 'admin', 
                        'uploads/profiles/admin.jpg', '1')";
    $tables = [$table1, $table2];

    foreach($tables as $k => $sql1){
        $query = $this->db->query($sql1);
        if(!$query)
            $errors[] = "Table $k : Creation failed ($this->db->error)";
        else
            $errors[] = "Table $k : Creation done";
    }

    foreach($errors as $msg) {
        echo "$msg <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $this->db->error;
}
```

Comment: Is this `MYSQLI_` or `PDO`. But basically I imaging you will need to connect to the newly created database before attempting to add tables to it and insert data to them

Comment: SHow us the code you use to connect to MySQL

Comment: why dont you use `db forge`? [https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html]

Comment: I am creating database and creating new database.php config file at the time of executing code. I want to perform create and insert command in that script.

Comment: I am able to create new database.php file and creating database but not creating tables using my script.

Comment: How can i select database at the run-time so that tables would be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should additionaly tell your script to use the database (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html)

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $db_name";
if ($this->db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $sqlUse = "USE $db_name";
  if ($this->db->query($sqlUse) === TRUE) {
    ...
  }
```